# How to bind select options to a JSON object using Angular?

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, dropdown, mat-select

I am attempting to build a web application that has a dropdown menu of industries.
This is what my current list looks like:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Industry" [(ngModel)]="selectedIndustry" >
<mat-option [value]="0">None</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="1">Aerospace</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="2">Banking</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="3">Chemicals</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="4">Defence</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="5">Education</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="6">Finacne</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="7">Gaming</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="8">Government</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="9">Healthcare</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="10">Insurance</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="11">Media</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="12">Mining</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="13">Resources</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="14">Retail</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="15">Telecommunications</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="16">Utilities</mat-option>
</mat-select>
<button mat-button (click)="loadJSON()">Create</button>
```

I also have a typescript file of JSON objects that I would like to connect to this list. This is the contents of the typescript file:

```
export class Industry {
id: Number;
name: String;

industry = [
  {id: 1, name: "Aerospace"},
  {id: 2, name: "Banking"},
  {id: 3, name: "CapitalMarkets"},
  {id: 4, name: "Chemicals"},
  {id: 5, name: "Defence"},
  {id: 6, name: "Education"},
  {id: 7, name: "Gaming"},
  {id: 8, name: "Government"},
  {id: 9, name: "Healthcare"},
  {id: 10, name: "Insurance"},
  {id: 11, name: "Media"},
  {id: 12, name: "Mining"},
  {id: 13, name: "Resources"},
  {id: 14, name: "Retail"},
  {id: 15, name: "Telecommunications"},
  {id: 16, name: "Utilities"}
  ]
}
```

Currently the dropdown list functions but like expected but when I clike the 'create button' . nothing happens. I cant figure out how to bind each of the dropdown option to the corresponding JSON object. I have seen the use of this below, which I have tried but I cant get it to work for me:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let i of Industry.industry" [value]=i>{{i.name}}</mat-option>
```

Ideally I need to be able to select an object (either linked to the list by value of name or something) and have the json load when create is clicked.

I'm just starting out so any help is appreciated.  As . I have a beginner level knowledge could you please explain your answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What JSON are we talking about here? do you have some sample data to work with?

Comment: at the moment no, eventually yes there will be more comprehensive json attributes for each object but just for the sake of trying to binding it first ‘Id’ and ‘name’ are all I have

Comment: Please check if my answer helps.

Comment: FYI: use [ngValue] instead of [value] to prevent null as string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have some data that you're going to get from a REST API, you can call the API in the `loadJSON` method:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { DataService } from "./data.service";

/** @title Select with 2-way value binding */
@Component({
  selector: "select-value-binding-example",
  templateUrl: "select-value-binding-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["select-value-binding-example.css"]
})
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  selectedIndustry;
  industries = [
    { id: 1, name: "Aerospace" },
    ...
  ];
  data$: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  loadJSON() {
    this.data$ = this.dataService.getDataById(this.selectedIndustry);
  }
}
```

I've created a `DataService` that has a `getDataById` method. This takes an `id` as an argument and then returns an `Observable<Array<any>>`. I've then assigned it to the `data$` property on the Component class.

I can unwrap the `data$` property in my Component Template using the `async` pipe. Something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Industry" [(ngModel)]="selectedIndustry">
    <mat-option disabled>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let industry of industries" 
      [value]="industry.id">
      {{ industry.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-button (click)="loadJSON()">Create</button>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>

<pre *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">
  {{ data | json }}
</pre>
```

Also, instead of hard-coding every single item in the industries array, I can use the `*ngFor` structural directive to loop through the items in the array and render the `mat-option`

Hope this helps and clears your doubts.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rikjto?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: So I wont be connecting this to an API. I was planning on having all of the json objects stored inside the application. So I was hoping i would be able to get the loadJSON() method to call the selected object from the typescript file of json objects. Is that possible with your solution? Also thanks for you solution!

Comment: I would suggest against doing that. Storing all that data right on the application would make the bundle size to bloat up. This might end up making the application load time high which we don't want. So I'd still recommend storing the data somewhere and then exposing it via REST APIs to get the relevant data over the network. If you still want the data to be local, you'll also have to find the relevant Object from the Array. I'll anyway update my answer with that approach if you want that.

Comment: Yes please, I would really appreciate that. At this point it is more of a proof-of-concept application. And again thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Here's the updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rikjto-sn18k1?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html)

Comment: if you're satisfied with the answer, please consider marking it as a solution, to close the loop.